# I have a pandas dataframe and want to pass each column into the kruskal stats function as separate arrays

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Right now I can create the pandas dataframe. I have the stats.kruskal function set up with the first 6 columns of the dataframe by using df.iloc. This works, but in my dataframe I have 33 columns and do not want to use df.iloc for each one. I am sure there is a more pythonic way of doing this.

```
#make a pandas data frame called df from an excel file, you should see data print in console
df = pd.read_excel(file_path, engine='openpyxl')

#print description of dataframe
print(df.describe())

#kruskal wallis test comparing the columns of dataframe
print(stats.kruskal(df.iloc[:3,:1],df.iloc[:3,1:2],df.iloc[:3,2:3],df.iloc[:3,3:4],df.iloc[:3,4:5],df.iloc[:3,5:6]))
```